# How to deal with NA values when registering curves in R fda package

Tags: r, matrix, na

I am trying to register a curve in the R fda package but am getting the following error message due to NA values within the data:

**Error in if (cosangle < 1e-07) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

the object data2 is a matrix of dim 36,12 and looks like this:

```
 A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L

 5.3  NA   3.9  3.4  NA   3.8  NA   6.1  5.0  NA   3.3  5.4

 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   1.0  NA   NA   NA

 1.2  NA   2.1  NA   NA   NA   NA   3.5  NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Where NA values are random throughout the matrix

The script I am using is as follows:

```
date<-seq(1, by=1, length=365)

rng<-range(date)
nbasisw <- 15
norder <- 5
basisw <- create.bspline.basis(rng, nbasisw, norder)

sites <- 1:12
nsites <- length(sites)

tfine <- seq(1, 18, len = 101)
tmat <- tfine %*% matrix(1, 1, nsites)

hgtffd <- smooth.basis(date, as.matrix(data2), fdPar.obj)$fd

y0fd <- deriv(mean.fd(hgtffd), 1)
yfd <- deriv(hgtffd[sites], 1)

y0vec <- eval.fd(tfine, y0fd)
yvec <- eval.fd(tfine, yfd)

coef0 <- matrix(0, nbasisw, length(sites))
Wfd0 <- fd(coef0, basisw)

lambda <- 1
WfdPar <- fdPar(Wfd0, 2, lambda)

reglist <- register.fd(y0fd, yfd, WfdPar)
```

This last line is when I get the error message
I know that the cause is NA values within the matrix but I not sure how to overcome this whereby I can register the curves ignoring missing values?

Comment: I know nothing of functional data analysis, but perhaps you could approach the problem by imputing the missing values in one way or the other?

Comment: FWIW, the authors claim that the FDA package can handle missing data. Given this outcome, I'm not sure what that means.